# read out actual iteration of foreach in smarty php?

Tags: php, foreach, iteration, smarty

I have one problem; I want to run a `foreach-loop` and in the loop shall be items with the actual iterating number created.

My code so far:

```
{foreach from=$bilder item=item name=foreach_gallery}
    {capture assign=shopBild}
       <img src="{page_url page=$item}" border="0" alt="{$item->field.name}" title="{$item->field.title}" />
    {/capture}
    <tr>
        <td width="250">
            {$shopBild|max_image_width:160}<br/>
            <input type="text" size="2" name="pic_id{$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration}" value="{$item->field.id}" readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
              {input type="text" name="articlename$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration" title="Artikelbezeichnung:"}<br/>
              {input type="textarea" name="description$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration" title="Artikelbeschreibung:"}<br/>
              {input type="text" name="articleid$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration" title="Artikelnummer:"}<br/>
              {input type="text" name="prize$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration" title="Preis:"}<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

it works fine for the

```
<input type="text" size="2" name="pic_id{$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration}" value="{$item->field.id}" readonly>
```

element but not in `{input ...}`. Any idea why it doesn't work in the second case and how I could solve this problem?

Greez Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution how to execute smarty in a smarty-tag:

```
{input type="text" name="articlename`$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration`" title="Artikelbezeichnung:"}
```

You need to wrap the smarty-code with ``

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<input type="text" name="articlename{$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration}" title="Artikelbezeichnung:">
```

instead of :

```
{input type="text" name="articlename$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration" title="Artikelbezeichnung:"}
```

hope i help you.

Comment: yeah this would work, but {input} builds an unique <input> with much more styles and div's around.

Comment: when you say it don't work, the problem is it display something like that : <input type="text" name="articlename$smarty.foreach.foreach_gallery.iteration" title="Artikelbezeichnung:">
or that : <input type="text" name="articlename" title="Artikelbezeichnung:"> 
or something else?

Comment: I found the solution and posted it as answer on my own Question I hope if some one others got a similar issue it will help him.